# Gmail X.509 certificate chain

Tags: certificates, x.509

I have asked about this on several forums but never got a straight answer. If the root certificate on a certificate chain has a different fingerprint to the root certificate available for download on the CA's website, does this mean the chain is faked?

The GeoTrust root certs can be viewed [here](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/)
None of them match the root cert on my chain which is;

**GeoTrust Global CA**
Identity: GeoTrust Global CA
Verified by
Expires: 08/21/2018

**Subject Name**
C (Country):    US
O (Organization):   GeoTrust Inc.
CN (Common Name):   GeoTrust Global CA

**Issuer Name**
C (Country):    US
O (Organization):   Equifax
OU (Organizational Unit):   Equifax Secure Certificate Authority

**Issued Certificate**
Version:    3
Serial Number:  12 BB E6
Not Valid Before:   2002-05-21
Not Valid After:    2018-08-21

**Certificate Fingerprints**
SHA1:   73 59 75 5C 6D F9 A0 AB C3 06 0B CE 36 95 64 C8 EC 45 42 A3
MD5:    2E 7D B2 A3 1D 0E 3D A4 B2 5F 49 B9 54 2A 2E 1A

**Public Key Info**
Key Algorithm:  RSA
Key Parameters: 05 00
Key Size:   2048
Key SHA1 Fingerprint:   C0 7A 98 68 8D 89 FB AB 05 64 0C 11 7D AA 7D 65 B8 CA CC 4E
Public Key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

**Extension**
Identifier: 2.5.29.35
Value:  30 16 80 14 48 E6 68 F9 2B D2 B2 95 D7 47 D8 23 20 10 4F 33 98 90 9F D4
Critical:   No

**Subject Key Identifier**
Key Identifier: C0 7A 98 68 8D 89 FB AB 05 64 0C 11 7D AA 7D 65 B8 CA CC 4E
Critical:   No

**Basic Constraints**
Certificate Authority:  Yes
Max Path Length:    Unlimited
Critical:   Yes

**Key Usage**
Usages: Digital signature
Critical:   Yes

**Extension**
Identifier: 2.5.29.31
Value:  30 31 30 2F A0 2D A0 2B 86 29 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 72 6C 2E 67 65 6F 74 72 75 73 74 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 63 72 6C 73 2F 73 65 63 75 72 65 63 61 2E 63 72 6C
Critical:   No

**Extension**
Identifier: 2.5.29.32
Value:  30 45 30 43 06 04 55 1D 20 00 30 3B 30 39 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 02 01 16 2D 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 67 65 6F 74 72 75 73 74 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 72 65 73 6F 75 72 63 65 73 2F 72 65 70 6F 73 69 74 6F 72 79
Critical:   No

**Signature**
Signature Algorithm:    SHA1 with RSA
Signature Parameters:   05 00
Signature:  76 E1 12 6E 4E 4B 16 12 86 30 06 B2 81 08 CF F0 08 C7 C7 71 7E 66 EE C2 ED D4 3B 1F FF F0 F0 C8 4E D6 43 38 B0 B9 30 7D 18 D0 55 83 A2 6A CB 36 11 9C E8 48 66 A3 6D 7F B8 13 D4 47 FE 8B 5A 5C 73 FC AE D9 1B 32 19 38 AB 97 34 14 AA 96 D2 EB A3 1C 14 08 49 B6 BB E5 91 EF 83 36 EB 1D 56 6F CA DA BC 73 63 90 E4 7F 7B 3E 22 CB 3D 07 ED 5F 38 74 9C E3 03 50 4E A1 AF 98 EE 61 F2 84 3F 12

Comment: Can you add some more detail? SHA1-fingerprints for each cert in question? Screenshots of each chain?

Comment: I added the root cert information to my question

Comment: That cert is NOT a root cert. As I explained, it's a BRIDGE cert that cross-signs "GeoTrust Global CA" under "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority". The root cert for that chain is the one labelled "Root 1 - Equifax Secure Certificate Authority" on the page you linked.

Answer (score 5):

Some public CAs have multiple roots, and more *use* multiple roots.

Assuming gmail means mail.google.com, as the [(currently two) reports at SSLLabs show](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.google.com) google uses its own intermediate CA, (CN) `Google Internet Authority G2` issued under (CN) `GeoTrust Global CA`.

That **Geotrust CA has a root cert** with (SHA1) fingerprint beginning `DE28`, **but also a nonroot bridge cert** (included in server handshake) with fingerprint beginning `7359` 
under (OU) `Equifax Secure Certificate Authority`; that Equifax CA in turn has a root cert with fingerprint beginning `D232` which was issued in 1998 so it was pretty well established and trusted when GeoTrust started in 2002 and initially was not trusted. Today the bridge cert shouldn't be needed, and pretty soon it will actually hurt because its chain expires sooner.

For more on Geotrust (and Google) anchoring, see:

- [google certificates correct CA](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53231/google-certificates-correct-ca/)
- [Different SSL cert behavior with Chrome on desktop vs. Chrome on iOS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89798/different-ssl-cert-behavior-with-chrome-on-desktop-vs-chrome-on-ios)
- [What happens when certificates further up the chain expires before mine? (Equifax/GeoTrust)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66487/what-happens-when-certificates-further-up-the-chain-expires-before-mine-equifa)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/589590/understanding-the-output-of-openssl-s-client

@Steffen's answer points to a comparable but slightly different case, multiple generations *within* Verisign.

**UPDATE 2017**: The Equifax root cert, and thus the GeoTrust bridge cert, are no longer valid using the MozillaNSS-also-curl truststore, see https://serverfault.com/a/841071/216633 .

Comment: Don't you think this makes it very difficult for ordinary users to verify? When you have an email provider constantly sending different certs, and the user doesn't know the intricacies of trust chains, surely this leaves the door wide open for MITM to send fake cert chains? I would like to test this, If I were to create my own root cert in open ssl and call it GeoTrust and then use it to sign a cert called google and then use it to sign a cert called gmail. Who would know that chain was fake ?

Comment: @scarecrow a relier trusts a (PKIX) cert chain if it ends at a root (or anchor) in the relier's truststore. If you create your own root cert and give it the same name as GeoTrust (or any other established CA), it won't have the same key, so it won't be the same cert that systems have in their truststore, and it won't be trusted. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity -- which actually uses gmail as the example!

Answer (score 4):

You can have different root certificates with different fingerprints which contain the same public key. This is actually not uncommon when you are in the process of replacing a root CA. See also [Multiple Versions of SSL Signing Certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93038/multiple-versions-of-intermediate-ssl-signing-certificate/93045#93045)